# Index of the congruence subgroups of $PGL_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-groups, p-adic-groups, p-adic-numbers

Let $\Gamma_n$ be the $n$-th congruence subgroup of $GL(2,\mathbb{Z}_p)$. So $\Gamma_n$ consists of matrices in $GL(2,\mathbb{Z}_p)$ which are congruent to the identity matrix modulo $p^n$. Let $Z(\Gamma_n)$ the the center of $\Gamma_n$.

My question is to compute the index $[\Gamma_n/Z(\Gamma_n):\Gamma_{n+1}/Z(\Gamma_{n+1})]$

I know that the index of $[\Gamma_n:\Gamma_{n+1}]=p^4$. I also know that if $G_n$ is the $n$-th congruence subgroup of $SL(2,\mathbb{Z}_p)$, then the index of $[G_n:G_{n+1}]$ is probably $p^3$

(because the topological generators of $G_n$ are $1+p^nE_{2,1}, 1+p^nE_{1,2} $ and $ (1+p^n)E_{1,1}+(1+p^n)^{-1}E_{2,2}$).

Here $E_{i,j}$ is the elementary matrix having $1$  at $(i,j)$-th place and $0$ elsewhere.

I can't figure out the the index $[\Gamma_n/Z(\Gamma_n):\Gamma_{n+1}/Z(\Gamma_{n+1})]$, that is the index of the congruence subgroups of $PGL_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)$.

Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: (Better asked on Math Stack Exchange...)

Comment: Garrett: I asked on Math Stack Exchange on Oct 13, without any reply. Here is the link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2953359/index-of-congruence-subgroups-in-gl-2-mathbbz-p-modulo-their-centers

Comment: Ah, ok, MathStudent. Hm. I'm mildly surprised that no one there answered. As a placeholder helpful-remark: this reduces to the analogous question over $\mathbb Z$, and prime-power congruence subgroups, via the fact that $\mathbb Z_p$ is the projective limit of $\mathbb Z/p^n$. In particular, $\mathbb Z_p/p^k\mathbb Z_p \approx \mathbb Z/p^k\mathbb Z$ and such. I don't think one needs to think about topological generators...

Comment: Garrett: Thanks for the reduction to $\mathbb{Z}$. It remains to find the index of prime-power congruence subgroups of $PGL_2(\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: if you ask the question about prime-power congruence subgroups over $\mathbb Z$ on MathStackExchange, people there might be less intimidated than by the $\mathbb Z_p$ case and "topological generators"...

Comment: The centre of  a finite index subgroup $\Gamma $ of $GL(2,{\mathbb Z}_p)$ is the intersection of $\Gamma$ with the group of scalar matrices since $\Gamma$ is Zariski dense in $GL(2)$ ). If $p$ is an odd prime, then $\Gamma _n$ is the product of scalars in $\Gamma _n$ and the intersection $\Delta_n$ of $\Gamma _n$ with $SL(2,{\mathbb Z}_p)$. This will reduce the computation to the index $[\Delta _n:\Delta _{n+1}]$ and that is $p^3$. For odd primes, $[\Gamma _n:\Gamma _{n+1}]$ should be $p^4$.

Comment: It's true, but not obvious, that $\Gamma_n/\operatorname Z(\Gamma_n)$ is a subgroup of $\operatorname{PGL}_2(\mathbb Z_p)$.  (*A priori* it need not embed in any quotient of $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb Z_p)$.)  Also true is that $\operatorname Z(\Gamma_n) \cap \Gamma_{n + 1}$ equals $\operatorname Z(\Gamma_{n + 1})$, so that you're just computing $[\Gamma_n : \Gamma_{n + 1}]\cdot[\operatorname Z(\Gamma_n) : \operatorname Z(\Gamma_{n + 1})]^{-1}$.

Comment: It may help to realise that most of these computations can be reduced to the Lie algebra; $X \mapsto 1 + X$ induces an isomorphism of $\operatorname{Lie}(\Gamma_n)/\operatorname{Lie}(\Gamma_{n + 1})$ with $\Gamma_n/\Gamma_{n + 1}$, with the hopefully obvious meaning of the notation.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. They are very helpful.

Comment: Lspice: Can you please explain why its not obvious that $\Gamma_n/Z(\Gamma_n) $ is a subgroup of $PGL_2$. If its not obvious, how to prove this?

Comment: @MathStudent, re: [your comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/321490/index-of-the-congruence-subgroups-of-pgl-2-mathbbz-p#comment802486_321490), $\Gamma_n/(\operatorname Z(\operatorname{GL}_2) \cap \Gamma_n)$ is obviously a subgroup of $\operatorname{PGL}_2$.  One needs to do a tiny computation to show that $\operatorname Z(\operatorname{GL}_2) \cap \Gamma_n$ is no smaller than $\operatorname Z(\Gamma_n)$.  (By the way, you need an `@` before my name to notify me automatically.)